# Django ORM Query output is strange

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a `CampaignEmailTemplate` and it has 3 records as below

```
==>CampaignEmailTemplate.objects.count()
==>3
```

2nd query and visible_to is many to many field

```
==>CampaignEmailTemplate.objects.filter(Q(private_template=True, visible_to=1) | Q(private_template=False)).count()
==>84
```

Model details

```
class CampaignEmailTemplate(models.Model):
    private_template = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    visible_to = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True)
```

I don't know why its 2nd query is giving me 84 count.

It should give me 3 or less.

Can anyone help me out to find the real issue with 2nd query?

I am using Django==2.0.6

Comment: Do you have a custom manager implemented for `CampaignEmailTemplate` model that could maybe change the behavior of `Queryset.count()`?

Comment: might have duplicates records in the queryset? please use `distinct()` before the `count()` [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct]

Comment: yes @NakulNarayanan its has duplicate records

Comment: can you post your model and any overridden methods

Comment: @OluwafemiSule there is no custom manager

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).